# F# error type 'X' is not compatible with type 'X'

Tags: c#, f#

First, my apologies. This post might be a bit too vague. I have a problem I cannot reproduce in a small sample code section. Here is what I do:

F# application uses a C# DOM, generated from an XML Schema (xsd.exe).

The instance of the DOM is created in C# and returned to F# application from a function call.

The instance (here named type is 'X') is stored into a f# record like this:

```ml
type Something = { Dom : X option }
```

Later in the code I have something like this:

```ml
match myRecord.Dom with
| Some(dom) -> CSharpCode.Save( dom, filepath )  // error: Type 'X' not compatible with type 'X'
```

So basically, I get the Dom instance from C# and pass it back. In the last line above, I get the error message mentioned in the title: Type 'X' is not compatible with type 'X'.

I have no idea what I should look for as in my simple sample program where I try to reproduce this, I never run into this error. Any ideas?

Comment: One guess - there are 2 different `X` types - one taken as the argument by `CSharpCode.Save` and the other in the definition of `Something`.

Comment: is it the only pattern matching case  ?

Comment: is the return type of Save(..) unit ?

Comment: I remember getting this error message when working with type proxies (Types that are generated by some other tools). Basically, there are two different types called X, one being the one you wrote, and the other one being the generated one. Maybe that's the problem here...

Comment: I left the | _ -> () out to keep the sample short. It is nothing simple like that.

Comment: @NikonTheTHird How did you fix it? I reference the c# assembly and use the full namespace for my type. In intellisense I do not see a double.

Comment: @Nicolas Yes, Save has unit return type.

Comment: @user2173833: OK, in my case it was quite easy. I recreated the proxies with the external program (they were service references) and specified a switch which instructed the tool to re-use existing types from a shared library. The problem was that the tool also recreated types from a shared library.

Comment: Before I discovered the switch, I had a dirty hack in place: A function that converted type X(1) to type X(2) (basically copying all the properties into a new instance). Dirty, and ugly, I know. But it DID work.

Comment: I fail to find out of I have the same problem (2 types with same name in same namespace). Object browser also only shows it once.

Comment: The object model code generated by xsd.exe looks like this:

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.42")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://myschemapath/myschema.xsd")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("definition", Namespace="http://myschemapath/myschema.xsd", IsNullable=false)]
    public partial class X : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {...}

Comment: Could the "partial class" be the problem? What is f# doing with that?

Comment: F# should be able to handle partial classes because they compile to the same classes everything else uses when the assembly's built, and that's the level it's interacting with them on.

Comment: Right, Mathew. The assemblies hide that and only export a class. I now decided to work around the unresolved issue. I use System.Xml.XmlDocument in the interface and convert to an XmlDocument in c#. This at least does not block my progress. I suspect I will not be the last one running into that problem. Would be nice to have a solution on this site.

Comment: What version of F# are you using? Are you running on the CLR (i.e., Windows) or Mono? Are you using Visual Studio (if so, which version)?

Comment: VS 2010 on Windows 8, btw.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this [troubleshooting page](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/troubleshooting-fsharp/#FS0001B), the phrase 'not compatible with type' seems to be used in the context of numerical values, rather than general type matching.

Another guess is that your code sample has `CSharpCode.Save( dom, filepath )`, but in F# function arguments are whitespace-separated rather than comma-separated, so I would have expected `CSharpCode.Save  dom  filepath`. Wouldn't your sample be constructing a tuple of `dom, filepath` and attempting to pass it to `.Save`?